# Does Google Glass Mirror API support WebRTC

Tags: webrtc, google-mirror-api, google-glass

The Glass Mirror Timeline API document suggests that video can be streamed to a Glass headset (https://developers.google.com/glass/timeline). I'm trying to determine whether this could theoretically work with a WebRTC connection? Documentation is limited around the browser/rendering capabilities of the timeline so has anyone tried something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Ran across a discussion about WebRTC + Glass in a reported issue - https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=2083

From the sound of things someone got it to work in chrome beta at 176*144. There were some audio/frame rate issues that appear to have been resolved.  Note though they talk about streaming video/audio from the glass to another machine not video streaming into the glass display.  I believe that at this point it will only work in chrome beta & doubt you could integrate this into the timeline smoothly, though with how hard Google is pushing WebRTC I would not be surprised to see increased support.   I'll be testing this out with my own WebRTC demos soon & will know more.

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC for Google glass has been reported: http://www.ericsson.com/research-blog/context-aware-communication/field-service-support-google-glass-webrtc/. There were some limitations, e.g. the device overheated after 10 minutes.

Another case - http://tech.pristine.io/pristine-presents-at-the-austin-gdg (thanks to [Arin Sime](http://www.realtimeweekly.com/))